# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Tenho um fragment que através de um botão ele ira chamar o outro fragment. Mas está aparecendo o seguinte erro.

```
06-20 19:12:12.075 17971-17971/com.example.gerdaumanagement.gerdaumanagement E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                           Process: com.example.gerdaumanagement.gerdaumanagement, PID: 17971
                                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                               at com.example.gerdaumanagement.gerdaumanagement.adicionar_usuario.<init>(adicionar_usuario.java:158)
                                                                                               at com.example.gerdaumanagement.gerdaumanagement.usuario.adicionarUsuario(usuario.java:42)
                                                                                               at com.example.gerdaumanagement.gerdaumanagement.usuario$1.onClick(usuario.java:29)
                                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

sendo que  o fragment que chama o outro fragment é:

```
public class usuario extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_usuario, container, false);

       // ListView listaUsuario = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listaUsuario);
        Button botao = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addUser);
        botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adicionarUsuario(v);
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;

    }


    public void adicionarUsuario(View view){


        adicionar_usuario adduser = new adicionar_usuario();

        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content,adduser, adduser.getTag()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }


}
```

Segundo o erro mostrado, está com erro na linha 42, que é o trecho:  `adicionar_usuario adduser = new adicionar_usuario();`

e meu fragment a ser chamado é o seguinte:

```
public class adicionar_usuario extends Fragment {


    public adicionar_usuario() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String TAG = "myApp";
        Log.d(TAG, "ENTROU!");
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_adicionar_usuario, container, false);

        Button botao = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.salvar);
        botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                salvarUsuario(v);
            }
        });

        //Alterar nome da actionbar
        ((MenuDrawer) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Adicionar Usuário");


        //TiPOS
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tipoFunc);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterTiposFunc = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.tipoFunc, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);
        adapterTiposFunc.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapterTiposFunc);


        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        if(intent != null){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if(bundle != null){

                usuario.setId(bundle.getInt("id"));
                usuario.setNome(bundle.getString("nome"));
                usuario.setEmail(bundle.getString("email"));
                usuario.setTipoFunc(bundle.getString("tipoFunc"));
                usuario.setNp(bundle.getString("np"));

                //nomeEt.setText(usuario.getNome());
                emailEt.setText(usuario.getEmail());

              //  senhaEt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                salvarBt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //editarBt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return rootView;
    }


    public class usuarioData {

        private  String nome;
        private String email;
        private String np;
        private String tipoFunc;
        private String senha;
        private int id;

      /* public usuarioData(){
           this.nome = nome;
           this.email=email;
           this.np=np;
           this.tipoFunc = tipoFunc;
           this.senha = senha;
           this.id = id;
       }*/

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getNp() {
            return np;
        }

        public void setNp(String np) {
            this.np = np;
        }

        public String getTipoFunc() {
            return tipoFunc;
        }

        public void setTipoFunc(String tipoFunc) {
            this.tipoFunc = tipoFunc;
        }

        public String getSenha() {
            return senha;
        }

        public void setSenha(String senha) {
            this.senha = senha;
        }


    }

    private usuarioData usuario = new usuarioData();

    private EditText nomeEt = (EditText) getView().findViewById(nome);
    private EditText emailEt = (EditText) getView().findViewById(email);
    private EditText npEt = (EditText) getView().findViewById(np);
    private Spinner tipoFuncSp = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(tipoFunc);
    private  Button salvarBt = (Button) getView().findViewById(salvar);


    public void salvarUsuario(View view){

        //usuario.setNome(nomeEt.getText().toString());
        usuario.setEmail(emailEt.getText().toString());
        usuario.setTipoFunc(tipoFuncSp.toString());
        usuario.setNp(npEt.getText().toString());

        db_funcao bd = new db_funcao(getContext());
        bd.inserir(usuario);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Usuário inserido com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }






}
```

e seguindo o erro apresentado no logcat, apresenta erro nessa linha: ` private EditText nomeEt = (EditText) getView().findViewById(nome);

`
Alguém sabe  motivo do problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

o método findViewById deve ser chamado quando sua view já existe, no caso do fragment, a view só é criada no método onCreateView.

Então você poderia fazer assim:

```
    private EditText nomeEt;
    private EditText emailEt;
    private EditText npEt;
    private Spinner tipoFuncSp;
    private  Button salvarBt;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String TAG = "myApp";
        Log.d(TAG, "ENTROU!");
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_adicionar_usuario, container, false);

nomeEt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(nome);
emailEt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(email);
npEt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(np);
tipoFuncSp = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(tipoFunc);
salvarBt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(salvar);

}
```